# Redirect to the same view after update,delete in Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, http

How can I redirect to the same view after I deleted object and pass some success message?

html:

```
<form action="{% url 'lamp-delete' lamp.id %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ lamp.id }}" />
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
```

views.py

```
 def index(request):
    lamps = Lamp.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'lamps': lamps})


def productlist(request, categ):
    MEDIA_URL = settings.MEDIA_URL
    lamps = Lamp.objects.filter(category=categ)
    return render(request, 'productlist.html', {'lamps': lamps, 'MEDIA_URL': MEDIA_URL})


class LampDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Lamp
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns =[
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^productlist/([a-z0-9]+)/$', views.productlist, name='productlist'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'productlist/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.LampDelete.as_view(), name='lamp-delete'),
]
```

I'm using django.views.generic.edit and now after successful deleting item using reverse_lazy I can redirect to static page, but I'm trying to overload the existing model and pass some variable with string to this view 'productlist'. If somebody could provide an example I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

[Classy Class Based Views](http://ccbv.co.uk) is a good resource for class-based views. Looking at https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.10/django.views.generic.edit/DeleteView/, you can see that there is a `.get_success_url()` method, and in there you will also have access to `self.request` to be able to pass some sort of variable.

*However*, for simple success messages, I would take a look instead at Django's [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/)

```
from django.contrib import messages


class LampDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Lamp
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.get_object()
        messages.success(request, '{} was deleted'.format(obj.name))
        return super(LampDelete, self).delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then in your template:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

(That's just the example verbatim from the Django docs.)